# multiple taxonomies in wp_list_categories' $args

Tags: taxonomy

Why doesn't it shows terms in both 'lunch' and 'dinner' taxonomies?
How can i do it?

```
  <?php 
    $taxonomy     = array('lunch', 'dinner');
    $orderby      = 'name'; 
    $hierarchical = 1; 
    $title        = '';

    $args = array(
      'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
      'orderby'      => $orderby,  
      'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
      'title_li'     => $title
    );
    ?>

    <ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you noticed in the list all of valid [Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Parameters) for `wp_list_categories()` function that `taxonomy` doesn't accept input as array, thats why you are not supposed to pass an array to it.

If you still want to be able to show terms of two different taxonomies, use [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) Wordpress function instead. The only bad is it won't provide pre-formatted list of Term Objects and their children, instaed it provides array.